# Update documents where two fields are in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection looking like that :

```js
{
   "name":"Frank",
   "age":23,
   "status":"ok"
},{
   "name":"Alice",
   "age":39,
   "status":"ok"
},{
   "name":"Bob",
   "age":42,
   "status":"ok"
},{
   "name":"Alice",
   "age":25,
   "status":"ok"
}
```

And I would like to update the `status` of all the documents where `name` and `age` match one of the objects in an array looking like that : `[{"name":"Alice","age":39}]` (in this example the 39 y/o Alice would be updated)

I can do that using updateMany and a $or to which I pass my array, the problem is that I created a unique compound index (on name and age) that it doesn't use.

So is there any way to do this task using indexes to make it fast ?

Comment: On what keys your compound index is on

Comment: I edited to answer that, thanks.

Comment: Run explain with the equivalent `find` query, using the "allPlansExecution" option to see which indexes were considered and how each performed.  If the collection is very small, all matching documents are near the start of the collection, or the update matches a sizeable fraction of the collection, it may actually be more efficient to _not_ use an index.

Comment: I realized it actually used another index, but the query is still pretty long so would there be another way to do what I want ?